# jQuery Hide section with span value exceeding value of range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to hide all sections with the containing span values exceeding/ not exceeding the current value of the range slider?

**HTML Range Slider:**

```
<span>Price from: </span><span id="price"></span><span> $</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" id="range"/>
```

**HTML Sections:** (examples)

```
<div id="main">

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span id="data">41,99</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span id="data">362,37</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span id="data">789,64</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

</div>
```

**My attempt in jQuery so far:**

Current value display in a span above the range slider: (working)

```
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var rdata = document.getElementById("price");
rdata.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
rdata.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Hide all sections with span values exceeding the current range slider value: (not working)

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
   var slider = document.getElementById("range");
   var rdata = slider.value;
   $("#main").find('#data').each(function () {
      return parseInt($(this).text()) < rdata;
   }).parent().parent().hide();       
)}
```

Comment: Change `id="data"` to class then `.find('.data')`

Comment: Should you be used a period instead of a comma here? 41,99, 362,37, and 789,64

Comment: The span data is always a price quotation with a comma. Unfortunately this can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the `section` within the `main` id element and loop over section element and `hide` it. `section` tag is not found by jQuery and you can define it as `div` with `section` class. You can find jsfiddle as well.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("range");
var rdata = document.getElementById("price");
rdata.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  $("span#price").text(slider.value);
  $("#mainDiv").find("div.content").each(function() {

  if(parseInt($(this).find("span#data").text()) < slider.value) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
  else {
    $(this).parent().show();
  }
});
}
```

Find the jsfiddle [Your fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbn82vm0/3/)

Comment: @user3087516 please check the jsfiddle i have created. There were some issue with your code.

Comment: Thanks! It is working, even "on the fly" while moving the ranger slider.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
     $( '#range' ).on( 'change', function() {
         var rdata = $( this ).val();
         $( '#main .content span' ).each( function () {
            if( parseInt( $( this ).text().replace( /\D/g, '' ) ) < rdata ) {
                $( this ).closest( 'section' ).hide();
            } else {
                $( this ).closest( 'section' ).show();
            }
         } );

     } );   
} );
```

Here is the updated [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/bc85oyh7/3/).

**Edit:**

> Another question: Is it possible that the hide function is working "on
>   the fly" moving the range slider and not only after the mouse click/
>   control?

You could do that by changing the event `change` to `input` in the above code.

Here is the new [`FIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/p6xL4yet/).

Comment: I see that you changed the max value of the range slider to 5000. Your code is working but ignoring the comma in the span data, falsifying the actual price quotation then.

Comment: Isn't that required? Anyway, you can tweak the code as required. This is just a working example.

Comment: Yes, I got it working now! Btw, the "closest" selector is amazing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Another question: Is it possible that the hide function is working "on the fly" moving the range slider  and not only after the mouse click/ control?

Comment: @user3087516 Great! Yeah, you can by changing the event `change` to `input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 

     $("#price").text($("#range").val());
 $("#range").change(function(){
  var slider = $("#range").val();
      $(".data").each(function(){
        let val = $(this).text();
        if(parseInt(val) < slider)
          $(this).parents().eq(2).hide();
        else
          $(this).parents().eq(2).show();
       });
  });
 
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Price from: </span><span id="price"></span><span> $</span>
<input type="range" min="0" max="100000" value="0" id="range"/>

<div id="main">

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span class="data">4199</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span class="data">36237</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

<section>
   <div class="content">
      <p>Current trade: <span class="data">78964</span> $ on the market</p>
   </div>
</section>

</div>
```

Comment: Problem: The span data is always a price quotation with a comma as in my source code.